# Transmitting data over ISO-TP (transport protocol) in CANoe using CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

Using CAPL with CANoe to transmit big amount of data via ISO-TP on CAN. Is there a routine, that provides the handling of data segmentation embedded in CAPL or do I need to write my own interpretation?

Comment: "consecutive frames" are you talking about ISO-TP?

Comment: Yes Transfer Protocol is used.

Comment: Do you mean Transport Protocol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the **OSEK_TP** CANoe demo. It shows how to transmit and receive data over ISO-TP (*Transport Protocol, ISO 15765-2*).
See the `nodeA.can` file and the OSEL_TP API reference for implementation details.

Here is minimal example:

Create and configure a connection:

```c
long handle;
handle = CanTpCreateConnection(0);    // 0 = Normal mode
CanTpSetTxIdentifier(handle, 0x700);  // Tx CAN-ID
CanTpSetRxIdentifier(handle, 0x708);  // Rx CAN-ID
```

Send data:

```c
BYTE data[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
CanTpSendData(handle, data, elcount(data));
```

To receive data, you have to implement the following callback function:

```c
void CanTp_ReceptionInd(long connHandle, byte data[])
{
    write("Received %d byte on connection %d: [%02x] ...",
            elcount(data), connHandle, data[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and hints. It is working like a charm now.