# How to send the Diagnostic IDs (DIDs) through CAPL script?

Tags: diagnostics, can-bus, capl, canoe

Currently, I am automating the test cases for testing the Gauges in the Instrument Cluster. I have come across changing the units from metric to US through DIDs. Can anybody help me how to send the diagnostic related stuff using CAPL script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this may be it works using `SendDiagRequest(reqobj)`;

===============================================================

1. Add respective CDD file in vector canoe
2. Set target ECU in Canoe settings
3. You have to define contents of service each byte value, can get those values in CAN trace
4. create object of services in CAPL and send it using SendDiagRequest(reqobj);

Comment: I didn't find the "SendDiagRequest" command in CAPL. Is it diagRequestSent?

Comment: DiagSendRequest(req_object)

Comment: I tried sending the DID of 5 bytes using message xxx sendMsg{dlc = 8};
output(sendMsg); this was successful.
But when i tried the same with more than 8 bytes (22 bytes in my case) which uses flow control concept, Can you please explain how to implement flow control concept in CAPL?
I don't have any idea about usage of DiagSendRequest(obj);

Comment: @AdarshKale To understand flow control please check the CANoe/CANalyzer documentation (e. g. online help) for [ISO-TP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15765-2) or read this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653095/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a diagnostic library loaded into CANoe (CDD/ODX/PDX, etc) then it will usually have the Transport Protocol defined which will segment your Tx and Rx where they are longer than 8 bytes.

Your post says that you are automating your testcases. This is done best in the test module of CANoe. If you have the CDD loaded you can drag the DID from the CAPL Browser Symbols pane (filtered by diagnostics) into the CAPL, e.g. drag "DID_01_ReadInfo" after diagRequest.

```
long size;
byte returnBytes[4096];
diagRequest  DID_01_ReadInfo  readInfoReq;   // diag request object
diagResponse DID_01_ReadInfo  readInfoResp;  // diag reponse object

diagSendRequest(readInfoReq); 

switch (testWaitForDiagResponse(readInfoReq, 2000)) // 2 sec timeout
{
  case 0: // timeout
          teststepfail("No reply from ECU");
          break;

  case 1: // response received

          if (diaggetLastResponseCode(readInfoReq) == -1) 
          { 
            teststepPass("Positive Response");

            // Get the number of bytes from the last response and store in 'returnBytes'
            diagGetLastResponse(readInfoReq, readInfoResp);
            size = diagGetPrimitiveData(readInfoResp, returnBytes, elCount(returnBytes));   
          }
          else 
          {
            teststepfail("Negative Response");
          }
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

long DiagSendRequest (diagRequest obj)

Comment: I tried sending the DID of 5 bytes using message xxx sendMsg{dlc = 8};
output(sendMsg); this was successful.
But when i tried the same with more than 8 bytes (22 bytes in my case) which uses flow control concept, Can you please explain how to implement flow control concept in CAPL?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do it:

```
fControlMessage(message 0x496 mystream)
{
    if (0x10 == mystream.byte(0) && Abfrage == 1) //First Frame von ISO_Lenkhilfe_Resp, erstes Byte auf 0x10 überprüfen
    {
       msDiag_FlowControl.byte(0) = 0x30; // Flow Control 
       msDiag_FlowControl.byte(1) = 0x0F; // Block Size ist 15
       msDiag_FlowControl.byte(2) = 0x00; // 20ms Abstand bei aufeinanderfolgenden Frame
       RequestLenght = mystream.byte(1);  // Gibt die Länge(Anzahl) der Datenbytes an
       RequestLenght = RequestLenght - 6; // 6 Byte Nutzdaten abziehen

        Abfrage = 0;
       //write("Send first Flow Control");
       output(msDiag_FlowControl);
}
```