# How to test N_As, N_Ar timeout parameters in CanTp protocol using CAPL script or or any other possible way?

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

As part of CanTp protocol related tests, I have been trying to test `N_As` and `N_Ar` timeout errors, where `N_AsMax = 1000ms` and `N_ArMax = 1000ms`.

Is it possible to create the `N_As` and `N_Ar` timeouts with CANalyzer and/or using CAPL?
It would be great help, if you can share a possible way to test these timing parameters using CANalyzer or CANoe.

Answer (score 1):

CanTP is a protocol to extendend the maximum data length (in bytes) of any given CAN data frame over the traditional 8 bytes, please refer to ISO 15765-2. Here you can have Single Frames, or Multi-Frames, which are trains of related frames each one carrying a portion of the overall PDU. A flow control frame is sent, usually by the receiver, to address and instruct the transmitter on the protocol to be used for frame splitting.

According to [docs](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-2/AUTOSAR_SWS_CANTransportLayer.pdf),

> `N_Ar` [is the] Time for transmission of the CAN frame (any N-PDU) on
>   the receiver side (see ISO 15765-2)
>
> `N_As` [is the] Time for transmission of the CAN frame (any N-PDU) on
>   the sender side (see ISO 15765-2).

In addition, the following requirements are relevant:

> **[SWS_CanTp_00075]** ⌈If the transmit confirmation is not received after
>   a maximum time (equal to N_As), the CanTp module shall act as if it
>   had received an unsuccessful transmission confirmation and any late
>   confirmation shall be ignored. The CanTp module shall cancel
>   (internally) the failed transmission. ⌋ ( )
>
> **[SWS_CanTp_00311]** ⌈In case of N_Ar timeout occurrence (no confirmation
>   from CAN driver for any of the FC frame sent) the CanTp module shall
>   abort reception and notify the upper layer of this failure by calling
>   the indication function PduR_CanTpRxIndication() with the result
>   E_NOT_OK. ⌋ ( )

Coming back to your question:

> Is it possible to create the N_As and N_Ar timeouts with CANalyzer and/or using CAPL?

Yes, by means of the `osek_tp.dll` file that you should have in your local CANoe install (I'm using CANoe v10.0). Examples on how to use it are well documented in the help document [AN-IND-1-012_CAPL_Callback_Interface.pdf](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-IND-1-012_CAPL_Callback_Interface.pdf), again it should be distributed in your CANoe install folder.

According to that document,

> Basically, the OSEK_TP.DLL implements fault injection functionality
>   that has to be enabled explicitly in order to prevent unintentional
>   usage. Once activated, it is possible to setup a specific fault on a
>   connection that is executed during the next data transfer.

I'd urge to give it a read, and refer to linked documentation as well. I hope this is pointing you in the rigth direction.

Additional info:

- [Transmitting data over ISO-TP in CANoe using CAPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626632/transmitting-data-over-iso-tp-transport-protocol-in-canoe-using-capl)